# Azure AD account sourced from another directory loops with SSO

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, kentico

I have installed an application (Kentico 8.1) to use with SSO, using Azure Active Directory.  The claims based authentication is working fine when the user is a member of the AD I created in Azure for the sole purpose of a POC.  We also have a corporate AD that I have access to through the same account, and I can Source a user from our corporate AD into my Dev AD, however when I log in with that user, I end up in what appears to be a loop...

```
Waiting for login.windows.net
Waiting for cms.domain.com
```

Firefox continually flashes those statements, until I finally stop the page load.

**Background:**

I have developed other apps inhouse, and not had any issues Authenticating users that were sourced from another domain.  The application is running on an Azure website, as was the other internally developed application.

Comment: is cms.domain.com your Kentico, or your corporate domain ? Also when you "source" user from corporate Domain - do you use Password sync, or SSO with ADFS ?

Comment: For sure, you can also track the actual HTTP loops and the messages being transfered to hunt the issue! There is one very common issue with Cloud services and authenticating - most CMS products to set the authentication cooke on root domain level (i.e. `.azurewebsites.net`, or `.cloudapp.net`) and all modern browsers just ignore those cookies. In that case you end up in a continuous loop! Oh, and last but not least - do you only have problems with those "foregin" accounts, or in general with Azure AD with that particular application (Kentico)